# PHP print json_encode($rows) shows nothing

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have two functions below that query the PHP and then print the json out.
I tried on my local machine AMPP Apache server, everything works with the Json printed. When I tried on my host machine (with all DB setup, tested good), somehow the `print json_encode($rows)` doesn't print anything on the remote host server.

So I added the debug `echo sizeof($rows)` below, and indeed there are 8 records as per expected. What can't the `print json_encode($rows)` print anything? How to further debug?

```
function queryPrintJson($cnx, $query) {
    $rows=queryReturnJsonArray($cnx, $query);       
    echo sizeof($rows);
    print json_encode($rows);
}

function queryReturnJsonArray($cnx, $query) {
    $result=mysqli_query($cnx, $query) or die ("Can't execute query!");
    $rows = array();

    while($obj = $result->fetch_object()){
        $rows[] = $obj;
    }
    $result->close();
    return $rows;
}
```

p/s: the same function works on the same remote host-server, for another db. It also works on my localhost.

*UPDATED
'var_dump(json_encode($rows), json_last_error())' shows `bool(false) int(5)`. Don't know what it means.

My query is simply `$newsquery = "SELECT * FROM newstbl where Status = 1";`

*UPDATE

After further debugging, I found that one of the field which is a `description` field that has long data... That field if omitted, everything works. But if included, it doesn't print out.

This also could imply not related to UTF-8 as well. As the `description` is all in normal english character. Hence doesn't seems like a duplicate of the other question.

p/s: Not sure who gave the down-vote to all the answers below, as it does help my debugging. Whoever does that need to be responsible before giving a down vote to the below answer. They all does help my debugging.

Comment: print_r( json_encode($rows));

Comment: `print_r( json_encode(($rows));` also check what is the output of `var_dump($rows);`. check and tell

Comment: Please run `var_dump(json_encode($rows), json_last_error())` and update the question with the information.

Comment: `print_r(json_encode(($rows))` doesn't work. `var_dump($rows)` get the array data shown as per expected.

Comment: use `fetch_assoc` to fetch data instead `fetch_object` also post your query

Comment: 'var_dump(json_encode($rows), json_last_error())' shows `bool(false) int(5)`. Don't know what it means.

Comment: Before return type `print_r($rows)` and post its value

Comment: You have an encoding error: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Comment: Your `host machine` could have a different config?May be errors suppressed etc?Check the logs.

Comment: your code not work properly

Comment: My code works well. I have it on my local host working. And I almost found the reason... The code works perfect (I didn't include the DB connection here, so if you copy verbatim you'll not get it work... as you need the DB).

Answer (score 0):

Add some debug tracing to find out what's going on:

```
function queryPrintJson($cnx, $query) {
    $rows=queryReturnJsonArray($cnx, $query);       
    echo sizeof($rows);

    // only for debug
    $tmp = json_encode($rows);
    var_dump($rows, $tmp);

    print json_encode($rows);
}
```

...and check what's wrong with the contents of your variables.

Comment: Thank much this help my debugging. Not sure who gave a down vote. I revote it back .

Answer (score -1):

`var_dump($rows)` to confirm there are values stored in it.
I guess if it's empty it's because you use `fetch_object()` instead of `fetch_assoc()`

And if that's correct use : `print_r(json_encode($rows,1))` to print out an associative array.

Comment: `var_dump($rows)` confim having value. Using `fetch_assoc()` and `print_r(json_encode($rows,1))` produces no result too :(

Comment: @Elye  why don't you put the output of `var_dump($rows);` in your question? more good if you use `echo "<pre/>";print_r($rows);` and put that result in your question by editing it.